# pointer to const and normal pointer can be mixed?

Tags: c

Is the value of *b undefined when printf() is called?

```
void foo(int *a) {
  const int *b = a;
  int *c = a;
  *c = 2;
  printf("%d\n", *b); // what must be *b? 1, 2 or undefined?
}

int d = 1;
foo(&d);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will print 2. `const int *b` literally means:

> Pointer to an integer whose value cannot be
>   altered through its dereferentiation.

This does not mean that the value the pointer points to may not change. In fact it's perfectly valid to change. A likely scenario to use this, are structures that keep a read only reference to some large structure. The reference may change, but the functions working with that structure may not change what's behind the pointer.

Imagine a driver or similar that hands out a read only memory mapping of whatever data the device delivered: The address of the mapping is not constant, but since this is a read only mapping the user program may not write to it. OTOH when the device updates the data the contents of the buffer will change, but not necessarily the mapping address.

Comment: Very solid explanation, you have to think about the fact, that the pointer object itself is just an address.

Comment: This was my case: an item in a struct defined as pointer to const for data that can be changed by other functions. It is my first time here, all answers were too fast!

Comment: @misianne: Indeed the word "const" when used this way with pointers is a bit misleading because makes you think to const-ness (immutability) while indeed it's more like "readonly". The key point is that when you say `const int *p` you are telling something about **the pointer** (i.e. that it cannot be used for writing), not about the **pointed object** (that can be not constant at all).

Answer (score 2):

What the Standard says is (emphasis is mine)

> 6.7.3/5
>
> If an attempt is made to modify an object **defined  with
>      a  const-qualified  type**  through use of an lvalue with non-
>      const-qualified type, the  behavior  is  undefined.

This does not apply to your situation (just the other way around).
The object in question was defined with a plain (`int`) type.

In your situation only changes to the object through `b` are illegal; changes through `a` or `c` are perfectly legal

Answer (score 0):

Since `b` points at the same memory as `a`, the value will of course change. Not sure why you also introduced `c` though, but it doesn't add anything. It will print `2`.

Comment: even if b is const and c isn't?

Answer (score 0):

`*b` would be 2 because the last line before the `printf` that sets the value is `*c = 2`.

`a`, `b`, and `c` all point to the same integer value. So the last one to set it will determine its current value.

Answer (score 0):

b should be 2 in printf(). You handle a pointer all the time in b and c.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `const int *b = a;` means that `b` refers to a constant int value. Which is to say that it treats its value as a constant value.

Thus,

```
*b = 10;
```

is incorrect, but:

```
a = 10;
```

is fine since a is not a constant value, but when dereferencing b we treat it as constant.

So `b` is certainly defined since you changed the value it pointed to:

```
c = 2;
```

which is the same as the example above. Simply put, a pointer to a const value cannot modify the value through dereferencing, but the value which it points to can otherwise be changed.